# Angular 8: Get ERROR Error: "[object Object]" in production mode

Tags: angular, production

when I use

> ng build --prod

for making a prod mode of my angular project I get this error

> ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
>   Ohttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.5b024d7013a56a12d0d8.js:1:13735
>   Ohttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.5b024d7013a56a12d0d8.js:1:13293
>   Dhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.5b024d7013a56a12d0d8.js:1:14523
>   invokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.5b024d7013a56a12d0d8.js:1:8735on
>   InvokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:434287
>   invokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.5b024d7013a56a12d0d8.js:1:8648
>   runTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.5b024d7013a56a12d0d8.js:1:3911vhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.5b024d7013a56a12d0d8.js:1:10964
>   main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:422504 $d
>   http://localhost:4200/main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:422504
>   CcnG/ephttp://localhost:4200/main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:422730 next
>   http://localhost:4200/main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:441083
>   CcnG/rlhttp://localhost:4200/main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:400910
>   FFOo/dhttp://localhost:4200/main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:565116
>   FFOo/dhttp://localhost:4200/main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:564258
>   FFOo/lhttp://localhost:4200/main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:563290
>   FFOo/lhttp://localhost:4200/main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:562973
>   K9Ia/dhttp://localhost:4200/main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:721405
>   CcnG/rlhttp://localhost:4200/main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:400676
>   onHandleError/<
>   http://localhost:4200/main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:434685
>   0TWp/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.5b024d7013a56a12d0d8.js:1:8060
>   0TWp/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.5b024d7013a56a12d0d8.js:1:3220
>   CcnG/Qphttp://localhost:4200/main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:435394
>   onHandleError
>   http://localhost:4200/main.97ca4e99c3abe316b59d.js:1:434647
>   0TWp/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.5b024d7013a56a12d0d8.js:1:8140
>   0TWp/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.5b024d7013a56a12d0d8.js:1:3475 t
>   http://localhost:4200/polyfills.5b024d7013a56a12d0d8.js:1:12356
>   0TWp/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.5b024d7013a56a12d0d8.js:1:12421 v
>   http://localhost:4200/polyfills.5b024d7013a56a12d0d8.js:1:11025

how can I resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Firstly : all imports are correct  ..secondly check that if you have a event handler in html then corresponding function exists in ts file like if you have  (click)='foo()' then foo  must be present ...AND

Comment: There might be error in project. Did you checked that?

Comment: @ChandanYS hi Chandan yes I check my project and I'm not found any error

Comment: @kunalverma, when I have an undefined function for an event handler, ng build get error

Comment: @karim  have you used auto import  to import  then sometimes it imports like ' ..' and such which works fine in  dev env  but results in error in prod

Comment: @karim Issue resolved? The error you posted is not enough to guess the answer.

Comment: @ChandanYS no, I already have this error. how can I complete my question?

Comment: @karim Which IDE do you use? I use Webstorm, as it shows validation errors before building it.

Comment: @Jadda I use vs Code

Comment: @karim: How about `ng build`? Does it show the same error? Try `ng build --prod --progress=true` or `ng build --prod --verbose=true` and paste the output here. Otherwise, it's hard to guess the answer.

Comment: @Jadda, of course, I using this : node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --base-href ./

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it occurres due to parameters count mismatch (when you're calling a function and in function declaration). Or you're calling function which is declared as private.

Although, your output is not informative, only guess is possible.